# Test auto increment function of web service with simultaneous users

Tags: web-services, testing, jmeter, soapui

I have a web service that does a simple task of 'auto-incrementing' a simple field.I test it using SoapUI. That is, whenever I run SoapUI, the response would be a value that is one plus it's previous value. Now, the catch is, I want to test simultaneous users running the same web service. Meaning, if they all access the web service at once, the web service will respond with the correct incremented value.

For instance, I have 3 users who accessed the service at the same time. I am expecting that the response (integer value) they would get will not be the same with each other. It should be incremental. That's what I want to test.

I'm thinking of maybe incorporating JMeter and SoapUI, but I'm not sure if that's even possible. Do you have any suggestions on how I can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI offers some [limited load testing capabilities](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/creating-and-running-loadtests.html) so if you think the load from one machine will be enough and you will be happy with the load test metrics which reflect only average/min/max response times and throughput - you can conduct your load test using SoapUI only.

If you decide to go for JMeter - be aware that you can migrate your test in at least 2 ways:

1. Record running SoapUI test scenario using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) automation framework comes with [SoapUI xml to JMeter jmx converter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-soapui-xml-jmeter-jmx).

If you want to do it manually check out [Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html) JMeter User Manual chapter

In order to "tell" JMeter to execute HTTP Request samplers with the desired amount of virtual users at exactly the same moment add [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child of the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.